# Setting setKeepAlive(true)

Tags: linux, sockets, serversocket, unix-socket

I am trying test a server where we reduced the keepalive params (default 7200 sec to 300) on RHEL.
I was setting:

```
    try {
        Socket tstSocket = new Socket(serverName, portNum);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(tstSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        tstSocket.setKeepAlive(true);
```

and wait 10min and check:

```
        out.println("output");
        if (out.checkError()){
            System.out.println("Socket closed");
            }
```

But if I set the setKeepAlive to true (should I just take this out?), does this mean the keepalivetime is no longer used?  (from the definition below)

tcp_keepalive_time -
the interval between the last data packet sent (simple ACKs are not considered data) and the first keepalive probe; after the connection is marked to need keepalive, this counter is not used any further.

Comment: Whats the problem statement? Its not clear..

Comment: If I set: .setKeepAlive(true); does that mean the current setting of tcp_keepalive_time = 300 is no longer used and will always be kept alive beyond the 300s setting?